# Tesseract does not recognize complete image whereas correctly recognizes part of it?

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I have to parse some Lab Reports and I am using Tesseract to extract data from them. I have encountered an issue that Tesseract does not correctly recognize the text if I pass entire page's image. But if I pass a small subsection of page (from `Test Report` covering the entire table till `*****`) it is able to read all the text correctly.

In the formal case (when I pass the entire image) it produces some random text output of English words which do not make sense. Part of text is as follows:

`Command I ran: tesseract -l eng report.png out`

```
Reﬁerence No : assurcAN, 98941-EU
5:er Nu (SKU) , 95942, 95943
Labelled age gwup “aw

Quamny 20 pweces

Fackagmg pmwosd Yes

Vendor

Manmamurer
```

But when I pass the subsection, I get accurate results.

What might be the issue here? How do I fix it?

See the sample report image:
[image]